# File read and write while reading the file line by line

Tags: c++, c, string, file-io, char

Program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    char* line;
    size_t ln=100;
    char* s;
    line=new char[100];
    s=new char[100];
    cout<<"input key"<<endl;
    cin>>s;
    f=fopen("parvin.txt","r");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        cout<<" no file TO read so creating for writing "<<endl;
        //return 0;
        f=fopen("parvin.txt","w");
        fputs(s,f);
        fputc('\n',f);
    }
    else
    {
        while(! feof(f))
        {
            fgets(line,100,f);
            cout<<line<<endl;

            //if(!strncmp(line,s,strlen(line)-1))
            if(strcmp(line,s)== 0 )
            {
                cout<<"duplicate found"<<endl;
                fclose(f);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        fclose(f);
        f=fopen("parvin.txt","a+");
        fputs(s,f);
        fputc('\n',f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Here the above program where **I like to read an input string and write it into file provided the string is not present already in file.**

- take input string
- open file in read mode.
- if it is first time entry file will not be there if file pointer return            NULL, create a file to write mode and write the
  inputted string.
- if file already there then read file line by line and compare with input string if match with any line then return and close.
- other wise open the same file in write mode and write the inputted string.

But it is not working properly..

> strcmp not executing properly.... with the duplicate entry also it
>   dont go into that loop of "duplicae found" .

please if anyone can help ...

Comment: You should not be using C and C++ methods together like that.  Choose one and stick with it...

Comment: I know but in " c" printf and scanf I hate to use them. format specifier you know... just for cin and cout I use that C++ lib..in original code  I will gonna use only c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fgets`:

```
fgets(line,100,f);
```

consumes the newline character from `f` and stores it in `line`. But `s` doesn't contain the newline character. So, the `strcmp` returns a non-zero number as the strings(`s` and `f`) are different.

Strip the newline character by using

```
line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
```

just after the `fgets`. The `strcspn` function, in your case, returns the number of characters until a `\n` in `line`. If `\n` is not found in `line`, it returns the length of the string `line`(`strlen(line)`).

---

Also, read [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). Replace

```
while(!feof(f))
```

with

```
while(fgets(line,100,f)) //Same as `while(fgets(line,100,f) != NULL)`
```

and don't forget to remove the `fgets` from the body of the loop to fix this issue.

Comment: Or to replace the whole C ugliness with C++ standard libraries.

Comment: using C++ , how to do the same ? I am not so aware about the c+ libraries for file IO

Comment: @PrvnYadav , I don't know much C++, but I think it is done via `fstream` or `ofstream` along with `cin` to grab input.

Comment: @PrvnYadav Here is a page outlining the basics http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Answer (score -1):

Use
    while(fgets(line,100,f)!=NULL)

Comment: That was not the problem ...problem was with the new line character in each line while comparing to inputted string.